# IOT Edge Certificate location

Tags: paho, azure-iot-edge

I am trying to create and connect to my IOT Edge Hub but keep running into paho-mqtt failing on `ssl.SSLCertVerificationError certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate`. How do I find the temp certificate that is created from my iot edge docker image thing? Am I just going about this wrong? Both device and iot edge are running on the the computer (raspberry pi 4, buster)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-create-transparent-gateway
This will be the helpful link, got it to work.